# AWS Error Message: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, wif

I'm working my way through AWS's Android SDK sample code. I have the S3_WIF_PersonalFileStore working. But I have an error that I can't fix in DynamoDB_WIF_UserPreference example. I think the problem lies in the Trust Relationship. But I'm using the same one, with appropriate value changes, as my working S3_WIF_PersonalFileStore.

My code successfully establishes a session with Facebook, then throws the following error:

04-03 09:42:15.949: E/(5161): com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: AWSSecurityTokenService, AWS Request ID: c41b700e-bb35-11e3-94ad-830da8959736, AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, AWS Error Message: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity

**wif.refresh() throws this error.**

I'd really appreciate any ideas on how to further diagnose this problem.

Thanks

Jeff

**My Trust Relationship Policy** from the IAM console:

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "graph.facebook.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "graph.facebook.com:app_id": "486879244768576"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

**My Role Permissions Policy** from IAM console
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action":"dynamodb:*",
            "Resource":"*"
        }
    ]
}

the relevant values in strings.xml:
486879244768576
    arn:aws:iam::532776582086:role/DynamoFbUserPrefExample

**My code** 
**wif.refresh()** throws the error. I am running AWS's sample code unchanged except for addition of some logging.

```
package com.amazonaws.demo.userpreferences;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityFederationSessionCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;

/**
  * This class is used to get clients to the various AWS services. Before
  * accessing a client the credentials should be checked to ensure validity.
 */
 public class AmazonClientManager {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "AmazonClientManager";

private AmazonDynamoDBClient ddb = null;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

private WebIdentityFederationSessionCredentialsProvider wif = null;
private WIFIdentityProvider idp = null;

private String fbRoleARN = null;
private String googleRoleARN = null;
private String amazonRoleARN = null;
private String googleClientID = null;

public AmazonClientManager(SharedPreferences settings, Bundle bundle) {
    this.sharedPreferences = settings;
    if(PropertyLoader.getInstance().hasCredentials()){
        this.initWithEmbeddedCredentials();
    }
    fbRoleARN = bundle.getString("FBRoleARN");
    googleRoleARN = bundle.getString("GoogleRoleARN");
    amazonRoleARN = bundle.getString("AMZNRoleARN");
    googleClientID = bundle.getString("GoogleClientID");
}

public AmazonDynamoDBClient ddb() {
    return ddb;
}

public boolean hasCredentials() {
    if (PropertyLoader.getInstance().hasCredentials()){
        return true;
    }
    return !(fbRoleARN.equals("ROLE_ARN") && googleRoleARN.equals("ROLE_ARN") && amazonRoleARN.equals("ROLE_ARN"));
}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return ( ddb != null );
}

public void clearCredentials() {

    synchronized (this) {
        AmazonSharedPreferencesWrapper.wipe(this.sharedPreferences);
        ddb = null;
    }
}

public boolean wipeCredentialsOnAuthError(AmazonServiceException ex) {
    if (
            // STS
            // http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/STS/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html
            ex.getErrorCode().equals("IncompleteSignature")
            || ex.getErrorCode().equals("InternalFailure")
            || ex.getErrorCode().equals("InvalidClientTokenId")
            || ex.getErrorCode().equals("OptInRequired")
            || ex.getErrorCode().equals("RequestExpired")
            || ex.getErrorCode().equals("ServiceUnavailable")

            // DynamoDB
            // http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ErrorHandling.html#APIErrorTypes
            || ex.getErrorCode().equals("AccessDeniedException")
            || ex.getErrorCode().equals("IncompleteSignatureException")
            || ex.getErrorCode().equals(
                    "MissingAuthenticationTokenException")
                    || ex.getErrorCode().equals("ValidationException")
                    || ex.getErrorCode().equals("InternalFailure")
                    || ex.getErrorCode().equals("InternalServerError")) {

        clearCredentials();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


public void login( WIFIdentityProvider wifIDP, final AlertActivity activity ) {
    idp = wifIDP;


    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"token: "+idp.getToken());
    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"provider: "+idp.getProviderID());
    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"arn: "+idp.getRoleARN());

    wif = new WebIdentityFederationSessionCredentialsProvider(idp.getToken(),idp.getProviderID(), idp.getRoleARN()); 

    //call refresh to login from an AsyncTask because refreshing requires the network
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Throwable>() {
        @Override
        protected Throwable doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            try {
                wif.refresh();  // ERROR ORIGINATES HERE
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                return t;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Throwable t) {
            if (t != null) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unable to login.", t);
                activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                activity.setStackAndPost(t);
            } else {
                ddb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient( wif );
                ddb.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
                AmazonSharedPreferencesWrapper.storeUsername(sharedPreferences, wif.getSubjectFromWIF());
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Logged in with user id " + wif.getSubjectFromWIF());
                activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            }
            activity.finish();
        }
    }.execute();
}

private void initWithEmbeddedCredentials(){
    if (ddb == null){
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials( PropertyLoader.getInstance().getAccessKeyID(), PropertyLoader.getInstance().getSecretKey());

        ddb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient( credentials );
        ddb.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Logged in with embedded credentials");
    }
}


public String getUsername() {
    return AmazonSharedPreferencesWrapper.getUsername( this.sharedPreferences );
}

public String getAmazonRoleARN() {
    return amazonRoleARN;
}

public String getGoogleRoleARN() {
    return googleRoleARN;
}

public String getFacebookRoleARN() {
    return fbRoleARN;
}

public String getGoogleClientID() {
    return googleClientID;
}
public void wipe() {
    AmazonSharedPreferencesWrapper.wipe( this.sharedPreferences );
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same or a different Facebook application? As you point out, the error definitely suggests an error in the trust policy. If you're running on a emulator have you tried resetting it to defaults to clear any cached session tokens?

Comment: I use a different Facebook application because Facebook requires the package be specified.  The two demos use different packages.  I am using a phone, not an emulator.

Comment: I also implemented Amazon Login this morning and received the same error. In other words, regardless of Facebook or Amazon login, I get Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.  The permissions policy works in my working S3 File version. I created the S3 permissions with CloudFormation.  I suspect there is step that CloudFormation knows but I don't when creating the IAM Role.

Comment: I worked around this problem by merging the DynamoDB example code into my working S3 example code.  Now the code both uploads and downloads S3 and performs all the Dynamo sample functions.  I had to modify the IAM Permissions policy to allow the Dynamo functions.  Again, it's a work around not a solution.

Comment: @Jeff of Brooklyn, what's policy do you have for your roles now?

Comment: I have the most liberal policy:{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": ["*"],
    "Resource": ["*"]
  }]
}

Comment: Same problem- with S3.